# Is there a way to use .envrc within crontab job script on ubuntu 18

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cron

We have a set of environment variables being exported from an .envrc file within a dir. In the shell you can run `direnv allow` and the .envrc file gets invoked, thus creating the env vars.

We would like to have this same functionality when running a script with a crontab job, but the envrc file never runs.

We have tried:

- In crontab:  `* * * * . $HOME/.profile; some/script/to/run`
- In script: `direnv allow`

  - OR
- In script: `eval "$(direnv export bash)"`

None of that works, is there a way to run the .envrc file from a script invoked by a cron job?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `direnv exec` to achieve this. It has the the arguments `[DIR] COMMAND [...ARGS]`. If the `.envrc` file is in the same folder as the script, you can change the following:

```
* * * * * sh /path/to/script/script.sh
```

To this:

```
* * * * * direnv exec sh /path/to/script/script.sh
```

If the `.envrc` file is in a different directory than the script, then you'll have to pass the path to the directory just after the `exec` argument like so:

```
* * * * * direnv exec /path/to/secrets sh /path/to/script/script.sh
```

[source](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/issues/367)